# 2 method calls for button click- exception handling

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a submit button. 2 methods to be called.

1. Java script function for validation of controls(Client)- onclientclick event
2. C# method button_submit_click (Server side database access)-onclick event.

When I run this application, 1st function works well; but an exception is thrown immediately for the 2nd function, because of empty values of the controls.

how can I handle this? I tried to call the 2nd fn from 1st one. But it is tedious.

I have an idea of using an If statement such as

`if(txt_name.Text!=="") { //my c# logic in default.aspx.cs }`

Any other methods advisable?

Comment: you are validating controls in javascript then why you need to validate again in c#?

Comment: I guess server side is for database operation @V2Solutions-MSTeam

Comment: no C# has database access logic! It is necessary that all controls should be typed by client. If he failed, the javascript validation throws a message to enter all the fields; but at the same time, 2nd fn gets invoked which uses the data of the fields. So an exception is thrown.

Comment: your javascript function return false or true?

Comment: @V2Solutions-MSTeam: You should always validate server side, even if you validated it client side already. The reason being is that it is really easy to bypass JS validation if you want to. If you assume that your client side validation will make sure you only get stuff you like then you might have a nasty surprise at some point in your future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `string.Empty`

```
if(!txt_name.Text.Equals(srting.Empty))
{
   //Some Code
}
```

This will check Null as well as empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking null or empty the textbox

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_name.Text.Trim())) { 
    //your code
}
```

Well as your code goes you must stop your form post until your form validates via javascript/Jquery .*This can be done by disabling the button until the form is validated*